# Change client from react (Next.js) to vue (Nuxt.js)

Tags: nuxt.js, api-platform.com, caddy

I want to change ReactJS to VueJS. My steps:

- Download api-platform ver. 2.6.2,
- Build images,
- Delete all files from **./pwa** (Dockerfile, and .* files left),
- Follow https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/nuxtjs/ with command prefix `docker-compose run --rm pwa ...`,
- Command `... yarn create nuxt-app your-app-name` creates **./pwa/your-app-name** directory so I move all files to **./pwa**,
- Once more build pwa images `docker-compose build pwa`,
- Run stack `docker-compose up`.

All request from localhost are going to `api` instead of `pwa` !? o0

Am I miss something from docs? I shouldn't delete files from **./pwa** (I don't want to mess with old React files, I want fresh install of Vue)?

Answer (score 0):

To fix an issue remember to update [caddyfile](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/blob/main/api/docker/caddy/Caddyfile#L18). Read paths from browser network logs and add them here.